# Match rows of 2 matrices for a minimum total sum of row-wise differences

Tags: matlab, matrix, rows, difference

I have 2 matrices with equal number of rows and columns. A(4x3) and B(4x3).

I would like to match rows of A with rows of B so that when subtracting I get minimum sum. Example of how inside of A and B look like:

```
A=  -0.3612   -0.1911   -15.3818
     0.0376    0.0206    0.3498
     0.0418    0.0229    0.3887
     0.0188    0.0103    0.1749
```

I'm doing this:

```
for j=1:size(B,1)
    [vv, inds]=min(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,A,B(j,:))),2));
    minJJ(j,:)=vv;  
    indsMatch(j,:)=inds;
    MM=min( minJJ);

    [A,ps] = removerows(A,'ind',inds);
    [B,ps] = removerows(B,'ind',j); 
end
```

I get the  error:

> Improper assignment with rectangular empty matrix.

What I'm trying to get with this is `indsMatch`. I want 'order of rows indexes' of matrix A that are paired with rows of B (based on min difference). Indexes of B is kept 1 2 3 4.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to do, but one problem with your code is you are cycling over every row of `B` (for this example `j` with go from 1 to 4). However, you are removing rows from `B` on every iteration, so this will result in an out of bounds exception. Maybe change the condition to cycle until `B` is empty?

Comment: Where does the function `removerows` come from?

Comment: What I wanted to do here is when the best rows match combination from 2 matrices found, remove those rows and iterate through the leftover(find match between left rows)..The answers given below are better though. and don't need loop..thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another vectorized approach. It tries all permutations of rows of `B`, and produces the optimal row-permuted `B` in matrix `Bresult`.

```
[m, n] = size(A);
ind = perms(1:m);                                  % // all permutations of row indices
BB = permute(reshape(B(ind.',:),m,[],n),[1 3 2]);  %'// all row-permuted B matrices 
C = sum(sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus, A, BB)),2),1);      % // compute the sum for each
[minsum, imin] = min(C);                           % // minimize
Bresult = B(ind(imin,:),:);                        % // output result
```

Answer (score 2):

Brute-Force, but vectoriced.

```
%// data
A = [ -0.3612   -0.1911   -15.3818
     0.0376    0.0206    0.3498
     0.0418    0.0229    0.3887
     0.0188    0.0103    0.1749 ]
B = flipud(A) + 0.2

%// number of rows and columns
[n,m] = size(A);
allcombs = perms(1:n).';  %'
%// all sortings of A
AA = A(allcombs(:),:)
%// repeat whole matrix B n! times
BB = repmat(B,factorial(n),1)
%// differences
D = bsxfun(@minus, AA, BB)
%// sum(abs( ... ))
E = blockproc(D,[n,m],@(x) sum(abs( x.data(:) )))
%// idx of minimum set
[~,idx] = min(E)

%// output
Aout = AA(idx:idx+n-1,:)
Bout = BB(idx:idx+n-1,:)
```

**This method will probably fail for n > 11 or even less.**

`blockproc` requires the **Image Processing toolbox.**

Comment: I haven't tried it for 11 but for 4 rows it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Besides the implementation error, your greedy approach of always picking the pair of rows with the minimum distance is wrong. Take for example this example:

```
A=zeros(4,3);A(:,1)=[0,1,2,3]
B=zeros(4,3);B(:,1)=[0,1,2,3]+.9
```

While the optimal solution would be not to permute anything, your code would first align row 2 to 4 if A with 1 to 3 of B with a total difference of `0.3` and then match 1 with 4 adding another `3.9` adding up to a total of `4.2` whereas the optimum is `4*0.9=3.6`

I am not aware of any approach better than brute-forcing all combinations.

To give you a good start implementing it right, first reduce the complexity of your problem. Calculate the distance matrix:

```
distanceMatrix=sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,permute(A,[1,3,2]),permute(B,[3,1,2]))),3);
```

It reflects the distance between the rows of A and the rows of B.

Comment: This works! Thank you! in permute when you use ordering [1,3,2] ,[3,1,2] how do I get order if it is more than 3 columns, e.g. 4?

Comment: The permute has nothing to do with the number of columns, the code is compatible to arbitrarily sized 2D-matrices as long as both matrices have the same number of columns. You only need to touch the permute for 3D-matrices.